# WPF ViewModel GC

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a ViewModel that on receiving an event from a Model, shows a dialog to the user by newing up the dialog's ViewModel and passing it to the dialog for data binding, i.e.,

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    ...
    private void OnModelRaisedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogViewModel dialogViewModel = new DialogViewModel();
        Window dialog = new DialogView(dialogViewModel);
        dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
 }
```

In the dialog's view I hook into a button click to close the window, i.e.,

```
public class DialogView : Window
{
    public DialogView(DialogViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s,e) => {DataContext = viewModel; };
    }

    ...

    private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
 }
```

Since only the DialogView is using the DialogViewModel, can I be confident that I won't get a memory leak here?

For example, if I open and close the dialog multiple times, will the DialogViewModel get GC'd when the DialogView is closed so not to accumulate multiple instances of the DialogViewModel. Watched memory usage in task manager, and it does go up when opening and closing DialogView multiple times, but not sure if this is because the GC just hasn't kicked in.

Comment: if each DialogView has its own viewmodel, why pass a new one in from outside?  Just let the DialogView assign its datacontext to a new DialogViewModel.  To contol the instances look into a locator pattern as a start.

Comment: Agreed, that would be the View-First approach. However, I'm just investigating if I can separate concerns further by giving the responsibility of creating the ViewModel to someone else (no DI at the moment). Do people always adopt a View-First or ViewModel-First approach with WPF?

Comment: *Watched memory usage in task manager* No. Don't do that. Not yours.  Memory management is the job of the genies the live in the CLR.  Their magic is not understandable by us humans. Do not look upon their works, lest ye despair.  In other words, allocating memory is expensive but releasing it is cheap. A .NET app will tend to allocate more memory and not release it over time unless it has to. Unless you're actually running out of memory, don't worry. And, when you do, use a real analysis tool, not Task Manager.

Comment: You already have several issues with your code. You have tight coupling to the View from your ViewModel, which is a validation of MVVM pattern. Neither EventHandler ('OnModelRaisedEvent') nor View types (`Window`, `FrameworkElement` etc.) belong to the ViewModel. Easiest way to assure this is to put ViewModels into it's own assembly with no reference to View (no reference to Presentation.dll or System.Window.* namespace/asemblies). This way its easy to spot a violation. If you try to use a class which referenced in one of these assemblies, you won't be able to use it and it tells you,its wrong

Comment: @Tseng Agreed I can put ViewModels into their own assembly, however I thought it was generally accepted that a one-to-one relationship exists between a view and its view model, and a one-to-many between the ViewModel and business logic models. In that sense, at least pragmatically, you'd pretty much always have single view associated with a single ViewModel.

Comment: @Tseng Also, doesn't your view need to know about the ViewModel for data binding? Providing you follow the ICommand pattern, you should be able to maintain loose coupling between the View and ViewModel.

Comment: The view assembly can safely reference the UILogic (ViewModel) assembly. But the UILogic one shouldn't have any reference to Presentation types. For example if you use something like `public Visibility IsVisible { get; set; }` that's a violation of MVVM pattern. `Visibility` is part of Presentation.dll, which is a WPF assembly. So you have an dependency on the View. If your ViewModel are in it's own assembly and this assembly doesn't have reference to presentation.dll, you won't be able to use this type (You'll get the missing reference error).

Comment: And this tells you, that what you tried to do is wrong and an violation and that you need to find another way to do this, which don't violate MVVM. And if using this approach you'd notice that `Window` and `DialogView` are also types which reference to Presentation.dll and that it's a no-no in MVVM :)

Comment: @Tseng Agree with the logic. I guess to ensure MVVM one would have to enable the Model (business logic) to create a dialog rather than a ViewModel. However, the examples I've seen have shown the ViewModel presenting the dialog in a manner similar to that shown above.

Comment: It's actually pretty easy. You'll have an `IDialogService` class in your ViewModel assembly. Just make sure it doesn't use any View types. So your ViewModels can reference this interface. The implementation of this interface you do in your View Assembly. When using Dependency Injection, you will always work with the interface and never know about the concrete implementation of it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78873/discussion-between-james-b-and-tseng).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you *do* have dependency injection right now, since you are injecting the viewmodel into the dialog via constructor.

While the dialog view is running, it contains a *reference* to `dialogViewModel` in `MainViewModel`.

When you close the dialog, the control is given back to the `OnModelRaisedEvent` method, and immediately after that, the method finishes (no other code after `dialog.ShowDialog()`) and GC collects the variable `dialogViewModel`, since its scope is restricted to that method.

So, the bottom line is: you should be able use your code without problems.

Comment: That's what I thought, but second opinion is much appreciated. Yes, I am using DI, I was really referring to an IOC container or some kind of service anti-pattern.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you could also set the dialogViewModel as the dialog's DataContext instead of passing it via constructor, but for a simple, self-contained and volatile dialog, I guess it doesn't make much of a difference.